# C++ header files for HDF5 are missing

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to compile a C++ program using g++ which uses the `H5Cpp.h` header file. g++ is producing a fatal error saying:

```
fatal error: H5Cpp.h: No such file or directory
```

I have already installed the library `libhdf5-serial-dev` and whatever else comes with it. I am using ubuntu 15.10.

Checked that `H5Cpp.h` is actually present in `/usr/include/hdf5/serial/` as per the file list of package `libhdf5-dev`.

Comment: Where exactly are you (or the compiler) looking? it seems to be in `/usr/include/serial` (whereas older releases might have placed it directly in `/usr/include`): see [File list of package libhdf5-dev in wily of architecture amd64](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/libhdf5-dev/filelist)

Comment: @steeldriver how do I check where is the compiler looking for the header? I checked in the directory (`/usr/include/hdf5/serial/`) from the file list that the header files are there in the proper directory.

Comment: You could either add `/usr/include/serial` to the include path (e.g. `-I /usr/include/serial`) or change the include directive in your source file from `#include <H5Cpp.h>` to `#include <serial/H5Cpp.h>`: if you want more explicit help you will need to provide details about your program and build process (compiler commands, Makefiles etc.)

Comment: Using `-I /usr/include/hdf5/serial/` helps **(not `-I /usr/include/serial/`)**. But now it gives some other errors, which I guess are not related to the question I have asked.. So I'm not sure whether to elaborate on it here or not. Also, its not any kind of complicated program, its actually an example from [HDF5 Group](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/crtdat.html). I am only doing `g++ myfile.cpp -o myfile_e -I /usr/...`, no other options or anything. If you add that comment with change of the path as answer I will mark it.

Comment: Have you tried using the `h5c++` helper script instead of running `g++` directly?

Comment: Yes, I was going through their documentation and found it 10-15 min ago. It works as intended, thanks for your help!

Comment: That's good - please consider posting that (i.e. using `h5c++`) as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the edit of the question, the files are there, but `g++` can't find them. The [HDFGroup](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5) tells us to use `h5c++` to compile programs which use hdf5 header files. As steeldriver mentions in the comments on the question, it is a helper script; I tested it, and it has solved the problem I was facing.

Comment: Is there a way how to manually link hdf5, should I be not so fond of `h5c++`?